# What triggers a nuclear chain reaction?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, atoms, strong-force

A nuclear fission works by spliting atom's neutrons by neutrons which release energy but how is the chain reaction triggered because at first the nucleus is bond by a strong nuclear force so what triggers the chain reaction when all the neutrons are stick together so tightly?

Comment: I think you mean splitting atom's nucleus not neutrons. Usually we bombard it with thermal neutrons to initiate chain reaction. Thermal neutrons are neutrons that are neither too fast nor too slow. In case of U-235 each fission emits 2-3 neutrons and thus it goes on by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uranium 235](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235) is naturally radioactive, with a half life of 703.8 million years. So if you take a lump of uranium 235 there will be nuclei decaying and releasing neutrons just due to its normal decay. These neutrons will then cause other nuclei to decay, and off goes your chain reaction.

So you don't need anything to start the reaction. All you need to do is control the conditions so the neutrons released by natural decay can get it going.

Answer (score 1):

Most fissile materials have some probability of spontaneous fission. For example in [uranium](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/wcbyz.jsp?z=92)-235, seven out of every billion decays are fissions.  These spontaneous fissions are the reason why a critical mass of fissile material may spontaneously develop a fission chain reaction.

Alpha particles incident on beryllium-9 will break the Be nucleus into two alphas and a free neutron with a probability of a few hundred parts per million. An alpha emitter alloyed with beryllium, with the alphas shielded, can be used as a neutron source; AmBe and PuBe sources are common. That isn't the main role that beryllium usually plays in reactors, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to the tunneling effect. If you have two states of low energy (here: single nucleus/two nuclei) with a high energy barrier in between (here: highly deformed nucleus), then it's possible to observe transitions from one state to another, even if there is insufficient energy in the system to climb the energy barrier.

A non-mathematical explanation is that due to Heisenberg uncertainty, you can borrow energy for a short period of time, but you can't borrow a lot of energy for a long time.